# Buck regulator load regulation voltage drop

Tags: buck

I've built a switched buck regulator using a TPS40057, schematic below, I followed the instructions in the datasheet and used the TI provided spreadsheet to calculate the loop compensation network (which I have no understanding of, but the values for the components look sane).

The ripple is OK under load, about 50mVPP although there is quite a bit of switching noise at the output, about 150mVPP. I need it to handle 3A without getting too hot (about 30C above ambient would be ok). At 3A the inductor gets warm (maybe 45C) but not hot.

The mosfets don't really get hot either, they are Infineon BSC093N04LS which can apparently handle the current I need. Under load, the voltage drops from roughly where it's supposed to be (about 5.95V at 0.1A) to about 5.45V at 3A.

I initially suspected the feedback trace from VOUT to VFB but ruled that out by jumping a 0.5mm copper wire to it, which changed nothing.

I wondered if the inductor was too small (6A rated) so tried a larger one (7.1A rated) which changed the output a bit but didn't solve the problem.

I measured the voltage at the feedback and sure enough it is 0.7V at very light load and drops to about 0.62V under load. But as I mentioned, even with a thick wire connection it still behaves the same. There is very little noise on it, <5mV.

The frequency is set at 325KHz.

I'm really stumped, can anyone see anything obvious? Are the graphs characteristic of a common error?

This is the schematic
[image: schematic]

The top side of the PCB looks like this, the darker green section in the lower left is SGND, the other green areas are PGND. Purple is VIN and light blue is VOUT, the feedback trace runs along the bottom to the resistor divider, 6mil wide. T1 at the left is where PGND is tied to SGND. It's a 4 layer board with layer 2 mostly ground, layer 3 is VIN pass through to the other side of the board and layer 4 is mostly ground and VOUT passed back to the left side.

[image: pcb]

And here's two graphs, the blue is using the smaller 6A inductor and 120K / 16K resistors in the feedback divider (VREF 0.7 so 5.95V), and the orange is the larger inductor and resistors 82K / 11K (= ~5.92V) - I tried lower values in case 120K was too high, the datasheet example used 100K for the top resistor.

[image: graph]

OK, I measured it wrong (at the wrong end of the cable, so there was a voltage drop due to the losses in the cable), this new graph has an added trace in green which is correctly measured. The actual drop starts between 0.6A and 1.1A, then tails off. I think the gradual linear drop after 1.1A is also measurement error but I can't get round it and it's not a concern. The big drop from 0.6 to 1.1A is the problem.

[image: real graph]

Comment: I would check the square voltage at the TN node, before \$L_1\$. It should swing close to \$V_{in}\$ during the on-time and close to zero during the off-time and be almost independent of the output current provided you use low \$r_{DS(on)}\$ MOSFETs. The open-loop output impedance of a buck converter operated in CCM voltage-mode control is equal to \$r_L||R_{load}\$ and this is divided by \$1+T_0\$ once the loop is closed so a fairly low output resistance (again considering \$r_{DS(on)}\$ MOSFETs).

Comment: It looks fine, really nice actually, very clean 0 to 24V square wave. What is unexpected to me is that the duty cycle doesn't change when the load changes. Like, at all really. This is counter to my understanding of how this thing should work.

Comment: Are you by any chance transitioning from DCM to CCM at the 0.9 A mark?

Comment: Ooh, that is an excellent question, I'm not sure how to find that out yet but will look into it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ok, if you have a real square wave then you are in CCM. If the duty ratio does not change while \$V_{out}\$ drops then the loop does not play its role. Is there any maximum programmable limit in this chip, like a max duty ratio for instance?

Comment: Everything looks good to me, so this is a bit of a reach -- might you have high ground currents disturbing the feedback?  If you're getting a bit of a square wave onto the feedback, *and* if the chip is sensitive to the timing of disturbances on the feedback or compensation networks, then you might see what you're seeing.

Comment: The voltage at VFB looks clean, very little ripple or noise, it's down in the low single mV range and looks like scope noise more than anything

Comment: @VerbalKint When you say 'the loop does not play its role' do you mean that the controller is failing to use the correct CCM/DCM mode due to the compensation network not doing its job?

Comment: No, the CCM/DCM transition is independent from the control section. A dc error can come from too low a dc loop gain (but it is unlikely considering the large open-loop gain of the internal op-amp) or an offset somewhere in the sensing path which alters the output measurement.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm still kind of at a loss as to what I should be looking for. I guess I'll closely measure VFB, presumably it's still drooping. If it is, I'll try to work out why.